# How to calculate the roll angle of a flat rectangular surface with different corner heights?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to work out the angle of roll (and then pitch) at the centre of a rectangle given that each corner has a different height (i.e. the rectangle is not level).

Can anyone provide any clues on how to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Does the rectangle come to you in terms of (i) Cartesian (spatial) coordinates of the corners; (ii) "Slopes" parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes, or a normal vector to the plane of the rectangle; (iii) Something else?

Comment: In cartesian coordinates - I have the length and width of the rectangle and height location of each corner.

Comment: Briefly, find the displacement vectors $u$ and $v$ for the edges of the rectangle by taking suitable differences of the Cartesian coordinates of corners. The components of the normalized cross product $\frac{u \times v}{\|u \times v\|}$ are [direction cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine) for a normal vector to the rectangle. Since there are many, many conventions for angles and rotations, I'm hoping this is enough to extract the data you need in a form convenient for you. :)